# Programmatic Spring JPA database access context for plain Java thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have a standard Java `ThreadPoolExecutor` thread that needs to perform transactional Spring JPA database interactions.

Although I found out how to set up an Entity Manager for the thread that allows me to perform some JPA interactions, this does not properly support transactions:

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
EntityManagerHolder holder = new EntityManagerHolder(entityManager);
TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(entityManagerFactory, holder);
```

Once I try to execute an actual (delete) query against the database, there is not valid transaction available:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:413) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.deleteById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    ...
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:282) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.remove(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$DeleteExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:274) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

How would I create the context (and tear it down afterwards) to successfully execute transactional JPA queries from a plain Java thread?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a dependency injection container, like Spring, you can use the @Transactional annotation on the method or class in which you call remove on the entity manager. This will ensure that every call in the stack trace will happen inside the transaction and also, if an exception is thrown all the changes in current transaction will be rolled back.

If you are not using Spring you will have to handle opening and closing the transaction yourself. Here is how you can do that:

```
   UserTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction(); 

try { 
    transaction.begin(); 
    transaction.commit(); 
} catch(Exception ex) { 
    transaction.rollback(); 
    throw ex; 
}
```

[Read this for more details](http://blog.jhades.org/how-does-spring-transactional-really-work/)
Hope it helps

Comment: @Transactional will only work if the code is injected by Spring, but this is in my case not possible. (I can only programmatically inject some startup and shutdown code.)
If I add the suggested `transaction.begin()`, then JPA complains there is already a transaction in progress. - I wish it were so simple. ;-)